# HTTP GET restful to do something

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm a little bit confused by what `verb` I should use / good practice for when I want to do something. For some context, I am building an API where I can get a collection of films. Naturally this fits in nicely within a restful context using a `GET` `http://foo/api/v1/films/name`. However, what if I wanted to translate that film given the type of film how would you approach this restfully? I have `http://foo/api/v1/translated/films` or `api/v1/films/name/translate`. This however isn't restful. A `post` doesn't make sense as I'm not creating anything. GET seems the right fit but also doesn't..

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a put verb because of your context needs update/translate something that already exist and the type of film you can send as a parameter.

Comment: My only concern with this is I'm not updating or creating any resource.. isn't it misleading or misusing PUT?

Comment: If you decide to use POST you could put in the return: 
return CreatedATAction(
   "Get",
   new {id=Model.Id}
)

Returns a Created (201) response with a Location header. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Today (2021-11-24), there is an unavoidable tension.

- If the semantics of the request are [essentially read only](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.2.1), then you should use GET.
- If the request requires a body, then you should NOT use GET, because within the context of a GET request, the body has no [generally defined semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.1).

So if you are trying to send (arbitrary) information to the server to get some information back, GET doesn't work (generally).

Therefore, you fall back to using POST.

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.” -- [Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

---

In the future, we should have another alternative to choose from.

Late in 2020, the HTTP working group voted to adopt a [GET-with-a-body](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body) proposal; the document is still in Draft status:

> Internet-Drafts are draft documents valid for a maximum of six months and may be updated, replaced, or obsoleted by other documents at any time.  It is inappropriate to use Internet-Drafts as reference material or to cite them other than as "work in progress."

So, someday maybe? we will have a safe method with a body, that can be used for messages like "please do something interesting with the body of this request, and send me a representation of the result".

Comment: It does seem GET is a reasonable thing to do but the way to reach it isn't very restful. I checked the Google translate API spec and they seem to use POST which seems like the right thing